# How create multiple Neo4j databases for multiple projects?

Tags: bash, neo4j

I have multiple projects using Neo4j and I'd like to separate them so I don't have to clear and reseed the database whenever I switch between projects. How can I do this?

I downloaded Neo4j using `brew install neo4j`. I start and stop neo4j using `neo4j start` and `neo4j stop`, but I think I just read that somewhere... there is no `man neo4j` or `neo4j --help`. And the documentation is terrible so I've been shooting in the dark for a while now.

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
neo4j start --path ~/projects/social-app/db/ --ip 127.0.0.1 --port 3002
```

This would create the database and run it on the local ip and port. Any ideas?

P.S. where the the documentation on this?

Comment: I created a small shellscript that does what you need: https://twitter.com/mesirii/status/614812510902984704

Comment: I just copy-pasted main folder ofneo4j server https://stackoverflow.com/a/58751637/3209523

Answer (score 5):

Neo4j doesn't support "schemas" or multiple databases as we know those features from more traditional databases like MySQL.

You have three options

1. Create script, which will do following

   stop neo4j
   change path for database in [neo4j_home]/conf/neo4j-server.properties (org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db)
   start neo4j
2. Have directory with Neo4j binaries for each project and just start instance which you need.

   - Also you can run each instance on different port (org.neo4j.server.webserver.port)
3. Use [Neo4j CLI Toolkit](https://github.com/neoxygen/neo4j-toolkit), but it's still in progress

Comment: how large are the Neo4j binaries?

Comment: with an editor of your choice, or sed, see here: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/docker-neo4j/blob/master/Dockerfile#L24

Comment: Neo4j binaries are around 50MB, depending on what you need to use.