# multiple versions of neo4j server at the same machine

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I downloaded 2 versions of neo4j on Ubuntu 18.04 which are "neo4j-community-3.5.12" and "neo4j-community-3.5.8"

I run 3.5.8 with default settings I can see it from the web. **http://localhost:7474/**

For 3.5.12 I changed **conf/neo4j.conf** file and set some other port numbers for not to conflict with the default ones.

3.5.8 version runs fine on :7474. When I start 3.5.12, the logs says it is running but when I check from browser it is not running. I tried 2 different port settings, none worked. Below is the log file. 
[image]

Why it is not running?

I see that many people recommended using docker. I also tried that.

I set up docker a container with command 
`sudo docker run --name db1 -p7474:7474 -p7687:7687 -d -v /db1/data:/data -v /db1/logs:/logs -v /db1/conf:/conf  --env NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j`

here I have an existing **/d1/data/databases/graph.db** folder. When I go to **localhost:7474** it is fine it shows me the existing database.

I set up **another** docker container with command 
`sudo docker run --name db2 -p3001:7474 -p3002:7473 -p3003:7687 -d -v /db2/data:/data -v /db2/logs:/logs -v /db2/conf:/conf --env NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j`

here I expect to see an **EMPTY** database but I see the already existing database again. When I go to the data folder inside db2. I see that it created some files here. WHY do I see the same database?

[image]

Also note that when I go to see the databases, headers of the web pages showing they are using the same bolt port?

can I copy the neo4j image and use different images to generate containers? Does that help?

I recognized that multiple databases are running and active **but somehow I'm not able to reach the second one through a browser.**

Comment: I am building the scenario, you have exposed same hosts ports for `db1 ` and 3XXX for image `db2`. When you explore neo4j using browser, It tries to connect to `bolt://<machineip>:7687` which is pointing to `db1` in both the cases.

Comment: This can be easily proved by exposing bolt service for `db1` on host port other than defaults i.e. you need to make change `-p7687:7687`. With this it won't find any service on the default port.

Comment: Let me rephrase, start both instances using above docker commands. Connect to db3 instance using machineip:3001. Then, type :server connect in the neo4j query box. Use conn. String: bolt://machineip:3003 and connect

Comment: I might try it sometime but for now I solved my issue by connecting directly to db using docker. `docker exec -it db1 bash` from docs https://neo4j.com/developer/docker-run-neo4j/ ps: there is no db3

Comment: `db3` was a typo it is `db2`

Comment: Thank you @Jatish it really worked. But since there are 2 connections somehow it redirects you (both localhost:7474 and localhost:3003) to the same database. First you should `:server disconnect` and then `:server connect`

Comment: It's a facility from neo4j to connect to defaults. The easy solution for you would be replace`-p 7687:7687` with any other random unused port as you did for `db2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the docker commands-

cmd1: `sudo docker run --name db1 -p7474:7474 -p7687:7687 -d -v /db1/data:/data -v /db1/logs:/logs -v /db1/conf:/conf  --env NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j`

---

cmd2: `sudo docker run --name db2 -p3001:7474 -p3002:7473 -p3003:7687 -d -v /db2/data:/data -v /db2/logs:/logs -v /db2/conf:/conf --env NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j`

The container ports are defaults exposed as the same host port for `db1` instance. Whereas for `db2` instance series 3xxx has been used.

To browse the UI provided by neo4j, you can use either `7474 or 3001` port which is mapped to `7474` container port.

---

Neo4j browser uses defaults (from neo4j.conf) to connect to neo4j server. The default settings are as 
`bolt://<machineip>:7687`, where `db1` instance has already exposed the container port to `7687` host port. 
A running instance is found on 7687 port which initiates a WebSocket connection for `db1` and `db2`.

---

How to connect to an appropriate instance?

1. Use: `:server disconnect` and `:server connect` with the appropriate `bolt://<machineip>:port` connection string
2. Map `db1` instance bolt container port to different host port (i.e. other than 7687)
   As no defaults will be available
3. (Preferred), set the same hostport:containerport combination e.g.

   cmd2: `sudo docker run --name db2 -p3001:7474 -p3002:7473 -p3003:3003-d -v /db2/data:/data -v /db2/logs:/logs -v /db2/conf:/conf --env NEO4J_AUTH=none neo4j`

   in this case, a Volume has to be mapped to provide `neo4j.conf` with updated values as `dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:3003`

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody still needs it: Here is how to run two neo4j databases neo4j_01 and neo4j_02 in two different docker containers, saving the data in different directories and accessing them on different ports.

docker container 1: neo4j_01

```
docker run \
    --name neo4j_01 \
    -p1474:7474 -p1687:7687 \
    -d \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_01/neo4j/data:/data \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_01/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_01/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_01/neo4j/plugins:/plugins \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=username/enterpasswordhere \
    neo4j:latest
```

docker container 2: neo4j_02

```
    docker run \
    --name neo4j_02 \
    -p2474:7474 -p2687:7687 \
    -d \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_02/neo4j/data:/data \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_02/neo4j/logs:/logs \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_02/neo4j/import:/var/lib/neo4j/import \
    -v $HOME/neo4j_02/neo4j/plugins:/plugins \
    --env NEO4J_AUTH=username/enterpasswordhere \
    neo4j:latest
```

After executing the code above e.g. neo4j_01 can be reached on port 1474 (when logging in you need to change the bolt port to 1687 in the first line and then enter username and password in second and third line)

You can stop a container with docker kill neo4j_01 and restart it with docker start neo4j_01. Data will still be there. It is saved in `$HOME/neo4j_01/neo4j/data`.

Doing it like this, I did not encounter any problems with ports/ accessing the wrong database etc.

Comment: I needed it, and this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Jatish This doesn't work for me. I have done it the same way. when connecting to localhost:1474 it's fine but I cannot log in.

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of effort, my solution is not to use docker.

Go and download a community server from here. https://neo4j.com/download-center/#community. It will give you a compressed file. Extract it. You will have a folder named like `neo4j-community-3.5.14`. Make a copy of **THAT FOLDER**. For each server instance, make a copy.

Inside the folder, there is a `conf` folder which has a file named `neo4j.conf`. Open that file. By changing some settings inside this folder, you can run many neo4j servers. Change the below settings

## To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:

`dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0`

## change some port numbers so that they won't intersect with already used ones

`dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=:3003
 dbms.connector.https.listen_address=:3002
 dbms.connector.http.listen_address=:3001`

Comment: How did you install multiple versions of neo4j?

Comment: What is not clear in my answer? Just make a copy of the main neo4j folder

Comment: The use case (and your problem, especially in the context of your question) is precisely what docker (and containerisation in general) is for. This is *not* the way to do it, use docker. Either https://stackoverflow.com/a/59107950/2469559 or the accepted answer are the approach.

Comment: @BenjaminR The practice and theory are ALWAYS very different. In the past, I spent lots of time on this problem and still I think my solution is the best for me. It might be best for others as well. I believe using docker for just running 2-3 instances at the same time is simply overkill